# PSQL json column not interpreting array as array

Tags: sql, json, nested, psql

I have a table on psql, where one column is called offer and is of type `json`, not as text. And the jsons inside have an attribute as an array. But when I extract that attribute into a column using the `->>` operator, I receive a text data type, not an array type. I would like to receive an array

That JSON column has these structure for every row

```
{"possible_amounts": [3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000],
 "possible_weeks": [4],
 "salary_multiplier": null,
 "is_scored": false}
```

However, if I run this query `SELECT offer ->> 'possible_amounts' as extracted_amounts FROM table_name` The resulting `extracted_amounts` column comes as text data type, and I can't apply array functions to it.

[image: Array as Text data type on psql]

Alternatively. I have seen there is also the `#>` and `#>>` operators to extract a specific index from an array attribute inside a json from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html) And it does works `SELECT offer#> '{possible_amounts,0}' as extracted_amounts FROM table_name`

[image: Extract array index from json in psql]

However, that only works to extract one value (the first one in my example), I would liek toe extract the whole array into a column of type array. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `->` operator to get the value in JSON format, in this case an array. The `->>` operator returns it as text.

```
SELECT offer -> 'possible_amounts' as extracted_amounts FROM table_name;
```

**Examples**

Select the whole array:

```
SELECT ('{
  "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
}'::json -> 'numbers') AS numbers_array;
```

Select the third array element:

```
SELECT (
  '{
    "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
  }'::json -> 'numbers' -> 3
) AS third_element;
```

Manual entry: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However if I use it with only one arrow, I get it as json data type. And then if I try `SELECT unnest(offer -> 'possible_amounts') AS amts FROM table_name;` it says the function unnest doesn't exists probably because it does not works on jsons? 

`ERROR: function unnest(json) does not exist`

Comment: @Eugenio.Gastelum96 My apologies, use jsonb_array_elements() instead. Cast from json to jsonb needed. Solution example updated.

Comment: But that would unwrap the array into rows right? What I am looking for is that if a row has a json column that holds an attribute that is an array, then the result should be a single row with a column of type array

Comment: @Eugenio.Gastelum96 Good point. I have now changed the examples to show how to use the array as an array without unwrapping it.